# base64 encoded PDF cannot be decode in swift

Tags: swift, pdf, coldfusion

I'm trying to generate a pdf from my iOS app which the content of the pdf is base64 encoded in coldfusion. I'm able the get base64string but I'm not able to decode it using the following code:

```
let decodeData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```

here's a part of the base64String

```
JVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwvRGVzY2VuZGFudEZvbnRzWzExOSAwIFJdL0Jhc2VGb250L1hJS1hIRitUaW1lc05ld1JvbWFuUFMtQm9sZE1UL1R5cGUvRm9udC9FbmNvZGluZy9JZGVudGl0eS1IL1N1YnR5cGUvVHlwZTAvVG9Vbmljb2RlIDEyMCAwIFI
```

Comment: Is it feasible to write a web service in ColdFusion to decode the content and call it from Swift?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for the answer:

```
if let decodeData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters) {
yourWebView.loadData(decodeData, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
} // since you don't have url, only encoded String
```